# Difference Score as Outcome Variable

Tags: regression, cross-section, pre-post-comparison

I am trying to evaluate the effect of a certain policy on the achievement gains of students between two points in time. However, not all the students are exposed to this policy. I am supposed to use  the gain score as a dependent variable.

After having read many critical articles about the use of gain scores as outcome variables, I would like to ask if somebody could tell me the advantages of this approach (compared to using the post-test score as an outcome variable while controlling for the pre-test score).

Is it wrong to say that only when using the difference score as an outcome I can really answer the question of whether competences of students grow faster when they are exposed to this policy? I feel like using the post-test score as an outcome variable does not precisely give me an answer to this question.

I would really appreciate if somebody could give me some advice on that

Comment: Almost a dup?  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are describing is well understood in the context of clinical trials, see for example Chapter 7.2.3 in [Senn (2008)](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Statistical+Issues+in+Drug+Development%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780470018774).

You may think that comparing difference scores (also known as *change scores*) and comparing post-test scores while adjusting for pre-test scores (also known as analysis of covariance, *ANCOVA*) are different, however, the former is actually a special case of the latter.

To see this, denote by $Y_{1i}$ and $Y_{2i}$ the pre- and post-test score of student $i$, respectively. Whether student $i$ received the policy is coded with a dummy variable $X_i$, which is 1 if they received it and 0 otherwise. The ANCOVA model is now given by
$$
Y_{2i} = \mu + \beta X_i + \gamma Y_{1i} + \epsilon_i,
$$
where $\mu$ is the average score when receiving no policy, $\beta$ the effect of the policy, $\gamma$ the influence of the pre-test score on the post-test score, and $\epsilon_i$ a random error.

The change-score model, on the other hand, is given by
$$
Y_{2i} - Y_{1i} = \mu + \beta X_i + \epsilon_i,
$$
which can be identified as a special case of the ANCOVA model with $\gamma = 1$ and $Y_{1i}$ subtracted from both sides.
In contrast, if we set $\gamma = 0$, we obtain a model where the post-test score does not depend on the pre-test score at all, the reality is probably somewhere in between.

What this means in practice is that the change-score model is a more restrictive model compared to the ANCOVA model. It may well be the case that the influence of the pre-test score is not equal to one, which in turn will reduce the efficiency of your estimate of $\beta$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer ! That really helps a lot.

Comment: But still, is there any advantage of the difference score over the "normal" ANCOVA model ? The supervisor of my thesis wants me to use the difference score variant and I don't really understand why

Comment: Senn recommends to choose ANCOVA over change-score analysis as the default approach. However, there are some deeper issues to be aware of, the famous [Lord's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord%27s_paradox), see for example [this blog post](https://errorstatistics.com/2019/08/02/s-senn-red-herrings-and-the-art-of-cause-fishing-lords-paradox-revisited-guest-post/comment-page-1/) by Senn or [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/3467/309868) which compiled a nice list of references.